# Pandas Profiling Not Working

Tags: machine-learning, pandas, visualization, data-analysis, matplotlib

I have been working on EDA lately and i got to know about Pandas Profiling ,
but i am unable to import the module Pandas_Profiling , I could import the module on Google Collab but couldnt import the specific function 'ProfileReport' needed for Profiling , can someone help me wiht it ? I really wanna learn it

Answer (score 4):

Something to note is that the package name will soon change to `ydata-profiling`, so we should use the new name. This is the announcement on [their Pypi site](https://pypi.org/project/pandas-profiling/):

> ⚠️ pandas-profiling package naming was changed. To continue profiling data use ydata-profiling instead!

Another thing to take into account is that the package is not installed by default on Google Colab, so we need to install it with (see [this Colab documentation snippet](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/importing_libraries.ipynb) for details on the ! syntax):

```
!pip install ydata-profiling
```

Then, we can import `ProfileReport`:

```
from ydata_profiling import ProfileReport
```

Comment: Please, consider consider accepting the answer (with the tick mark ✓ next to it).